# Is this an accurate depiction of arbitrary state transition?

Tags: state-transition, state

I'm looking for a bit of clarification. I'm trying to understand and help explain arbitrary state transition vs protocol-level state transition. I made a (very simple) graphic based on info from this interaction on StackExchange ([What does it mean that Solidity can encode arbitrary state transition functions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71278/what-does-it-mean-that-solidity-can-encode-arbitrary-state-transition-functions#new-answer?newreg=5644aaef6f684465aabf097cff5910f7)) and I'm hoping someone can confirm that my graphic does in fact explain the concept in a clear and accurate manor. [image]Any help is appreciated! (Graph created using excalidraw)

Comment: Ethereum's whitepaper is a comparison with Bitcoin where the "state" transitions are carried by a script language which isn't Turing complete so it can't create complex algorithms. Something missing in the graph is that Ethereum has a "World State" that where contracts update their state. Perhaps the closest is the second graph from this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/757, where state root is the root of the "World State" at each block.